# Laravel ReflectionException 'Class does not exist' error though everything is perfect

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-10, laravel-api

In my laravel api, I have this folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

And my code for `routes/api.php` here

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/admin', 'as' => 'api.v1.admin.', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1\Admin'], function () {

    //Page Settings: Favicon, Logo, Title, Metadata
    Route::post('settings/media', [PageSettingsController::class, "storeMedia"])->name('settings.storeMedia');
    Route::apiResource('settings', PageSettingsController::class, ['only' => ['index', 'update']]);

    //About
    Route::apiResource('about', AboutController::class, ['except' => ['show']]);

});
```

After running `php artisan route:list`, I am getting this error-

[image: error message]

I tried in so many ways, but filed. What can be the reason behind it? Do you have the solution?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.